# Python regex specific word with singe quote at end

Tags: python, regex, string, alphanumeric

Searching a large syslog repo and need to get a specific word to match with a certain condition. 
I'm using regex to compile a search for this word. I've read the python docs on regex characters and I understand how to specify each criteria separately but somehow missing how to concatenate all together for my specific search. This is what I have so far but not working...

```
p = re.compile("^'[A-Z]\w+'$")  
match = re.search(p, syslogline, )
```

the word is a username that can be alphanum, always beginning with an uppercase character (preceded by blank space), can contain chars or nums, is 3-12 in length and ends with single quote.

an example would be: `Epresley01'` or `J98473'`

Comment: `This is what I have so far but not working` .... can you expound? wrong output, error, something else? Can you also list expected input and output and MCVE?

Comment: When you say `proceeded by a blank space` I assume you meant `preceded`?

Comment: With the assumption above (preceded rather than proceeded) does `(?<= )[A-Z][^\W_]{2,11}'` work for you?

Comment: that does appear to work! Thanks so much. Now I'll have to reverse engineer it to see what is going on.

Comment: @PidePython I've converted my comment to an answer with an explanation of where (I believe) your pattern was incorrect.

Comment: @PidePython is the length of the entire username (including `'`) 3-12 characters or is the just the part before the `'` that's 3-12 characters in length?

Answer (score 1):

### Brief

Based on your requirements (also stated below), your regex doesn't work because:

1. `^'` Asserts the position at the start of the line and ensures a `'` is the first character of that line.
2. `$` Asserts the position at the end of the line.

Having said that you specify that it's preceded by a space  character (which isn't present in your pattern). You pattern also checks for `'` which isn't the first character of the username. Given that you haven't actually given us a sample of your file I can't confirm nor deny that your string starts before the username and ends after it, but if that's not the case the anchors `^$` are also not helping you here.

#### Requirements

The requirements below are simply copied from the OP's question (rewritten) to outline the username format. The username:

- Is preceded by a space  character.
- Starts with an uppercase letter.
- Contains `chars` or nums. I'm assuming here that `chars` actually means letters and that all letters in the username (including the uppercase starting character) are ASCII.
- Is 3-12 characters in length (excluding the preceding space and the end character stated below).
- Ends with an apostrophe character `'`.

---

### Code

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/096f84/1)

```
(?<= )[A-Z][^\W_]{2,11}'
```

---

### Explanation

- `(?<= )` Positive lookbehind ensuring what precedes is a space  character
- `[A-Z]` Match any uppercase ASCII letter
- `[^\W_]{2,11}` Match any word character except underscore `_` (equivalent to `a-zA-Z0-9`)

  - This appears a little confusing because it's actually a double-negative. It's saying match anything that's not in the set. The `\W` matches any non-word character. Since it's a double-negative, it's like saying <strike>don't</strike> match <strike>non-</strike>word characters. Adding `_` to the set negates it.
- `'` Match the apostrophe character `'` literally

Comment: This is really helpful. so essentially, each instance of parentheses, backets and {} is how you add the criteria together?

Comment: Brackets in regex `{}` don't have any special meaning (are interpreted literally) unless you put numbers in it. There are basically 3 formats it can follow: `{x}` (exactly `x` number of times: so `{2}` means exactly twice), `{x,y}` (between `x` and `y` times: so `{2,4}` means between 2 and 4 times - 2,3,4 are valid), and `{x,}` (`x` or more times: so `{2,}` means 2 or more times). Some other cases exist where brackets are used, but that's when a special character precedes it. For example in some regex engines `\p{L}` can be used (matches Unicode letters - letters in any script).

Comment: @PidePython See [Regular-Expressions.info](https://www.regular-expressions.info/quickstart.html) for more information. Also `\x{FFFF}` for Unicode characters.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks so much @ctwheels. Was reluctant to post this for a long time  but glad I did. Much appreciated.

Comment: hi the pattern you gave me works great. but in very rare cases in my search, there is no  ' (single quote)  at the end of the username. A real pain...but if I remove the ending ' from your pattern, I obviously get more hits but I do NOT get the Username that does not have the ending '  This is baffling me. Does the pattern require a space at the end if I remove the ' ?

Comment: @PidePython if it's sometimes a space and other times a `'` you can use `[' ]`

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it like this:

*(Updated after the comment from @ctwheels)*

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/Wifz1I/2)

```
 [A-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]{1,10}'
```

**Explanation**

- Match a whitespace
- Match an uppercase character `[A-Z]`
- Match `[a-zA-Z0-9]+`
- Match an apostrophe `'`

[Demo](http://rextester.com/LNRG22124)

Comment: No need for the lookahead: ` [A-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]{1,10}'` performs much better.